# how to use jquery.getjson while keeping an apikey secure?

Tags: jquery, json

I am looking for a solution for my problem...

My problem is that I want to call a json response from a server using `.getjson` but the server requires me to use my `apikey` which I **don't** want people to get hold of.

The json URL is similar to `http://website.com/this/and/that/query?apikey=APIKEY`

```
var apikey = "" //<--- how to make this secure?

$.getJSON("http://website.com/this/and/that/query?apikey=" +apikey, function(result) {

...

});
```

My thought on how this could be done:

- Call a file with an encoded string and decode as the variable? **still not safe**

Is this possible, or should I be looking into a different solution?

Comment: If the API key has to be put in the URL it will be visible to anyone. There is nothing you can do about this. An alternative would be to call the API form the server side and make your AJAX request to that local endpoint without the API key.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan `$.getJSON` doesn't show the end result url?

Answer (score 2):

You could always perform the actual API call from within your server and **only have the client trigger the API call**. This way, your API key will never be exposed to anyone.

The only problem with this solution is that you are creating **extra overhead for each API call** - you first need to make a request to *your* server and only then does the server make the actual API call.

Depending on your situation, the extra request might still be worth it if you need to keep the API key hidden from your end users.

Comment: Hmm, not sure how much access I have to the server. I use hostgator, so I have access to the options on the dashboard. Don't think they let people change direct server things to set up the callback. Maybe I'm wrong, I'll chat to them sometime about it.

Comment: @SaiyanToaster - Yes - you *will* need to write some server side code in order to implement my suggestion.